# ERROR: Service 'pgadmin' has a link to service 'postgres:pgsql-server' which is undefined

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin, portainer

I have two files. The text.yml has two services. I deployed using docker-compose successfully. However when I created pos.yml by adding one more service, I'm getting the above error. I'm unable to find whats wrong here. I didn't get any service link error in text.yml.

[text.yml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfTuKbHKPJJw86fXR-gCaysBrgdfQu2J/view?usp=sharing)
[pos.yml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ebDii4fUNGeeXqqucWZkaWNcDyZIZ_O-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please include the text of your compose files in the question. You only need to include the minimum configuration necessary to reproduce the problem. If the linked files expire, this question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: A total guess based on the question title, since you haven't included a [mcve] in the question: Compose `links:` are obsolete and you shouldn't need them at all, and maybe removing that section of the file would help?

Comment: I’m sorry. I was having a very hard time pasting the code in the format. Anyways I’ll repost the same soon.